# I used volley library to parse json and logcat not showing error but still no output on screen.Can someone tell where did i make a mistake?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, runtime-error, android-volley

```
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query? 
        format=geojson&starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02&limit=10";

        JsonObjectRequest JSONRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if(response!=null) {
                            JSONArray features = response.optJSONArray("features");
                            for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject feature = features.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject properties = feature.getJSONObject("properties");
                                long timeinMilliseconds = properties.optInt("time");
//earthquakes is a java class for storing data
                                earthquakes.add(new news(properties.optString("place"), properties.optDouble("mag"), timeinMilliseconds, properties.optString("url")));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(JSONRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just based on the JSON parsing code I didn't see anything wrong, but it is hard without having the part for displaying your earthquakes.
Are you basing your code off of the Volley documentation? https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request#java